# Simple way to load/save clipboard to tempfile w/hotkey

Tags: windows, clipboard, synergy, ditto

Is there any app for Windows that can literally save the current contents of the clipboard to a specific tempfile with predefined and unchanging filename without prompting when one key combo gets pressed, and load the contents of that file into the clipboard when a different key gets pressed? For example, shift-ctrl-c ("copy like you REALLY MEAN IT") copieswhatever's currently selected into the clipboard and saves it to c:\clipboard.clp (replacing whatever was previously saved), and shift-ctrl-v loads c:\clipboard.clp into the clipboard (replacing whatever was in the clipboard) and pastes it?

I'm trying to find an alternative to Synergy+'s dysfunctional clipboard-handling that lets me just copy and save to a file on a networked drive, and load & paste from the same file. I've tried Ditto, but I can't find any way to get it to work reliably in general (it works sometimes, but not always) when I try configuring it to hide its prompts. For what it's worth, the clipboard content is RTF -- sometimes images, sometimes formatted text, sometimes both. The file itself is purely a way to get the data from one computer to the other.

Answer (score 3):

AutoHotKey can do exactly what you're looking for. This script should do it:

```
^+c::
clipboard =  ; Start off empty so ClipWait can detect when the copy completes
Send ^c
ClipWait
FileAppend, %ClipboardAll%, C:\clipboard.clp
return

^+v::
FileRead, Clipboard, *c C:\clipboard.clp ; *c must precede the filename
Send ^v
return
```

See http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm for details.

Answer (score 0):

I find a shared folder and a tailing text editor is good.  "Notepad++", "Notepad2" and "Textpad" will all do tailing I think.  On Linux "gedit" is perfect as it doesn't bring up a modal dialog when it detects a change.
I just point my tailing editors to the same file, then copy what I want, paste it to the editor, save.   All the other editors then pick up the change.
Synergy does a pretty good job of handling text, other data is more complex as it needs to translate from one OS to another.
Also be aware that MS Office and VMWare can totally screw your clipboard without any help from Synergy!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ClipWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ClipWait.htm) function of AutoHotKey will do what you ask for.